# Trouble Setting Up Docker Compose for Next.js and Express.js Project: Build Order Dependency Issue

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to set up a Docker Compose configuration for my Next.js and Express.js project. The issue I'm facing is that Next.js requires the Express server to be running during its build process to cache some pages , but Docker Compose doesn't ensure the correct order, causing build failures.

I've tried using depends_on Docker builds without success. Any advice on how to properly configure Docker Compose for this setup would be greatly appreciated!

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
 backend:
  container_name: backend
  image: backend
  build:
   context: ./server
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
   - 8080:8080
  restart: always
   
 frontend:
  container_name: frontend
  image: frontend
  build:
   context: ./client
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
   - 3000:3000
  restart: always
  depends_on:
   - backend

# networks:
#  app-network:
#   driver: bridge
```

i've tried depends_on : but i thin kthat for starting not building process
also i want to mention that if i tried
`docker-compose up -d backend`
after the server is up , i run
`docker-compose up -d frontend` 
still same issue , nextjs while building cant access localhost:8080 (express server)

Comment: You can't do this as you're describing it.  (What should happen if you build the images, push them to a repository, and run both containers on a remote system without rebuilding either?)  What does the "caching" step look like; can you potentially do it at container startup?